# Can I run a docker container with an own, externally and host accessible, IP address on a Mac

Tags: macos, docker

I want to run an WebRTC gateway in a docker container on my Mac.

I need to export essentially all ports (TCP and UDP) (Specify -p does not help because there seems to be limit on the number of ports) with its own IP address. Using --net=host does not work on Mac.

Is there another option?

Answer (score 1):

You can expose all ports using `-P` (note the uppercase) or `--publish-all=true` (is the same) on docker run command.

[Link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/) to docker docs about this.

Then you can check the mappings docker assigned using:

```
docker port yourContainerName
```

Comment: -P seems to only forward exposed ports to arbitrary ports. I need to export all ports and to keep the port numbers

Comment: Yeah, I know... maybe you can do that with iptables I think.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer is identical to a similar question (about doing essentially the same thing on a different platform (ie Windows)).

The problems encountered on both platforms are different (because Mac OX and Windows have a different network stack), but the workaround is the same.

I think the answer (would help someone) encountering the problem (on both cases).